# Sequence contains no elements using string.equals

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, linq

When executing the following code I get the error message 'Sequence contains no elements':

```
public PartialViewResult access (string usern, string passw)       
{ 
  string pw;
  var useraccess = (from check in myfirstDB.Users 
                    where check.Name.Equals(usern) 
                    select check).Single();
    ...
}
```

However, if I insert a literal in place of the variable `usern` the code works as expected.  I'm certain that the record exists in my table.  I'm using jquery to call the controller like this:

```
 $('#access-form').click(function () {
       $.ajax({
           url: '/home/access',
           contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'html'
       })
       .success(function (result) {
           $('#access-field').html(result);
       })
       .error(function (xhr, status) {
           alert(status);
       })
   });
```

Comment: I don't see where you are calling /home/access with any parameters for usern, as such it will be null.  Because it's null, it won't return any records.  Change it to ''/home/access?usern=foo' or whatever the username should be.

Comment: I'd recommend putting a breakpoint at the access function and check the value of usern before running the query

Comment: If I modify the function to return a string as such:

Comment: public string access (string usern, string passw)       
{ 
  return "Username: " + usern + " Password: " + passw;
    ...
}

Comment: It returns the string variables that I expect to be passed to the function.  (My apologies for the segmented comment)

Comment: So I've modified my javascript function to  $('#access-form').click(function () {
       var uname = $('usern').val();
       var pass = $('passw').val();
       $.ajax({
           url: '/home/access',
           contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
           data: {un : uname, pa: pass},
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'html'
       })

Comment: and still the same results.